# How you decompress an array of shorts[][] using for loops?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, compression

I have to create a decompress method that is passed a compressed array of shorts created from another method in my program. It's basically RLE, with the first value being the number of times a value is repeated and the second being the value itself.

I'm not the best with for loops or arrays - I'm really trying to get better - so this last part of my assignment is throwing me off. Can anyone help or point me in the right direction?

```
public static short[][] decompress(short[][] cmpArray){     
        int position = 1;
        short[][] dcmpArray = new short[cmpArray.length][cmpArray.length];

        for(int i=0; i<cmpArray.length; i++){
            for(int j=0; j<cmpArray[0].length; j++){                


            }
       }

       return dcmpArray;
}
```

I know that I have to assign the incoming values to the new array - "dcmpArray" - and that should be done inside the for loop. I'm having problems on separating the values and then determining how many times the value should be printed in the new array. I was going to use "position" to determine the position in which index the value should be printed, but I'm having a brain fart..

Comment: It makes no sense to have a 2-dimensional array in this situation.

Comment: How is it run-length encoded? Also, `short[][] dcmpArray = new short[cmpArray.length][cmpArray.length];` is probably wrong.

Comment: (And, BTW, the above does not qualify as an answer for "What have you tried?")

Comment: You'd have to scan the data first to figure out how long it is, before you can allocate the array for it.

Comment: Okay, I will definitely remove the for loop. That might be why I'm not getting anywhere.

Comment: The data is scanned through another method and then returned as a an array of shorts, which is passed to this method.

Comment: A one-dimensional array of shorts, or a two dimensional array?

Comment: If you already have an array of shorts, why do you want another one?

Comment: Were you given any code as a starting point, and if so - what was that code? (It would be helpful to know what we cannot change, and what we can in your solution).

Comment: OKAY! This is my first time posting, so I'm sorry that I did not clarify this in my original question.

My passed array is one dimensional and must be converted into a two dimensional array.

I need another array of shorts because it is the required output of this assignment.

Comment: My code as a starting point is only the method header.

Comment: `cmpArray` is a two dimensional array also. If you want to asign value's to `dcmpArray` then use this in the nested for loop: `dcmpArray[i][j] = cmpArray[i][j];` But im not sure if that is what you are looking for, since you just said that the passed array is one dimensional. Also change `cmpArray[0].length;` to `cmpArray[i].length;`

Comment: let's just say the original array was 1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6. So my cmpArray prints: 41241516. dcmpArray should print out: 1,1,1,1,4,4,5,6.

Comment: "My passed array is one dimensional and must be converted into a two dimensional array."  So how do you know how to split up the array??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why your array would be 2 dimensional, but for a 1-dimensional array containing a series of shorts with RLE like you specify, this would be how to decompress it:

```
public static short[] decompress(short[] input) {
    int outputLength = 0;

    /* First we need to figure out how long the output is
       going to be when uncompressed, so we iterate through
       the input like we are would normally, but write no output,
       instead computing the output length */

    //note the += 2; we want to skip the actual output
    for(int i = 0; i < input.length; i += 2) {
        outputLength += input[i]; //increment target length
    }

    /* Now that we know what the output size will be,
       we can create an array to store it. */
    short[] output = new short[outputLength];

    /* Now iterate over the input, putting every other input short
       into the output, duplicated the number of times of the current input 
       AKA: decompression of RLE */
    for(int i = 0, outOffset = 0; i< input.length; i += 2) {
        for(int ii = 0; ii < input[i]; ii++)
            output[ii + outOffset++] = input[i + 1];
    }
    return output;
}
```

If your 2-dimensional array is simply an array of input arrays, then simply perform that procedure on each of the input arrays.

Comment: Thank you very much for not only helping but taking the time to explain in your comments of the method. The overall goal is to learn! Your outputLength is the idea I had for my position but yours is much better!